# Cordova geolocation plugin not working correctly if gps not available for a moment

Tags: angularjs, cordova, gps, geolocation

in my angularjs/ionic application I'm running a tracking service as a background service.

For that I run a geolocation watch. Well if for some reason the device (Iphone 5s) not getting gps signals the app is not able to get any gps signals after that. No matter where the device is. The only way to bring the tracking service back again is to open the default maps application. After the maps application locates my position, my application is getting gps signals too. It's complicate to explain the problem so sorry if I couldn't explain the problem good.

My code looks like this:

```
var startWatch = function() {

  var watchOptions = {
    frequency : trackingFrequency*1000,
    timeout : 60*60*1000,
    maximumAge: 10*1000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true // may cause errors if true
  };

  //watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);
  watch = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(on_success,on_error,watchOptions);
};

var on_error = function(err) {
  alert("Bitte schalten Sie die Ortungsdienste ein und starten Sie die Applikation neu.");
  startWatch();
};
```

I tried both plugins, the $cordovaGeolocation plugin from ngcordova and the default plugin but the behavior in both case are the same. If I lose the gps signal its completely lost until I use a native app to start the gps-tracking. I tested on Android and IOS and Android is running also in the same problems.

The only way to keep the tracking service alive is to stay in the areas where a good gps signal is and thats not a good solution.

So what am I missing?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: When you say "the app is not able to get any gps signals", does this mean the `on_error` function gets called (if so what's the error code) or does neither the `on_success` or `on_error` get called again at all?

Comment: Yes neither the on_success or on_error get called again. If I change the timeout to a little value, than the on_error function is getting called.

Comment: timeout of 60*60*1000 is too long - it's 1 hour until on_error will be called; a realistic value to allow for GPS acquisition would be more like 30000 (30 seconds). What error code is being passed to on_error() ?

Comment: Also you said "I'm running a tracking service as a background service". Are you using the [background geolocation plugin](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) or have you implemented a custom Java service on Android and manually registered Background Mode as Location on iOS?

Comment: No I'm using https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode as background service but I have written a own tracking service for handling the watch and getposition events. 

In my on_error function I tried to start the watch again but if it runs once into the error function it does not coming out of it and thats why I use 1 hour as error function.

Comment: I've edited my post so you can see the on_error function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an error code and/or message in the error object passed to `on_error`. This should tell you what type of error is occurring (I would assume it is TIMEOUT). The error code value corresponds to the [PositionError object](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#constants):

```
PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED = 1;
PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
PositionError.TIMEOUT = 3;
```

Also, when attempting to reset the watcher on error, make sure to clear the existing watcher before adding another. So try something like this:

```
var watch = null;
var startWatch = function() {

  var watchOptions = {
    frequency : trackingFrequency*1000,
    timeout : 30*1000,
    maximumAge: 10*1000,
    enableHighAccuracy: true // may cause errors if true
  };

  if(watch !== null){
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watch);
  }
  watch = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(on_success,on_error,watchOptions);
};

var on_error = function(err) {
  alert("Bitte schalten Sie die Ortungsdienste ein und starten Sie die Applikation neu." + "\ncode: " + err.code + "\nmessage: " + err.message);
  startWatch();
};
```

Comment: So is it better to use smaller timeouts on the watch and restart the watch manually instead of waiting for a signal with a big timeout?

Comment: That's the way I do it in my cordova apps that use geolocation and it seems to work. Setting a smaller timeout means you can be notified sooner if there's an issue with the GPS signal and respond to it.

Comment: For example, on Android if the user turns off GPS (set Location Mode to Battery Saving) then back on (set Location Mode to High Accuracy), the cordova app will not receive a location update until the watch is removed then added again.